# Writing an App with Android Studio to watch a Live Video which is provided by a Camera

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, connection

I am currently working on a project. I have learned Java for ~4 years and am completely new to Android Studio.

In this project, a camera with artificial intelligence should recognize people within a certain radius.

With an Android app that I want to program using Java via Android Studio, I want to access the camera and query the information.

My question would be, with which tool or library can I program such an app and what else do i need?

I tried to use OpenCV and also Exoplayer, watched several different tutorials, but nothing really worked out for me.

My question would be, with which tool or library can I program such an app and what else do i need?

Comment: If you want to analyse incoming live camera data you'll probably need to do some image analysis using CameraX, here's a tutorial on the basics: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0 The whole "AI that recognises people within a certain distance" bit is, uh, ambitious for a first Android project, and if you're looking for that kind of specialised advice on such an advanced topic, you'll probably have to provide a bit more info on your research and needs than "watched some tutorials but they didn't work out"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
The recognition is done on a different device and doesn't need to be included in the Application.


I just want to write an App which can display a Live Stream from an external camera (not the users phone) like a CCTV camera.



The problem is, I don't know how to connect a camera to my App.

Comment: Oh if you just want to display a video feed and that's all, I think that's gonna depend on the camera. Ideally you'd probably want to stream the video over a network, but you'll have to see if the camera can do that, what format it uses etc, if you need a server to actually store and stream the data (which it sounds like you're doing anyway, if the feed is being processed on another device)... If you have that set up and you're having trouble getting Exoplayer streaming working, you could post a question then (you might want to get a test stream working from a video on the internet first)

Answer (score 0):

I thought using histograms might be the right apporach. I looked around and found this intersting project. https://isl.cs.technion.ac.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Face_Recognition_Project.pdf

Introduction
Our goal was to create a fully operational mobile application which could detect,
recognize and track human faces.
In order to do that, we have decided to use the Android[3] platform combined
with the opencv library[4][5].
The development of the application was made on Qualcomm MSM8960[6] mobile device which run a 4.0.3 Android OS.
In addition to the application we have built, we also did a research about how
well we can use LDA[1] and PCA[2] in order to recognize faces and also about
the use of LDA in order to do basic pose estimation.

This is also interesting: https://towardsdatascience.com/face-recognition-how-lbph-works-90ec258c3d6b